# Head Node not updated outside Scope [Single Linked List]

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have explained where I'm currently stuck at the bottom.

This structure below is my **node** .

```c
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}

struct node *head;
```

I have already alocated memory to head node.

`head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

And created a bunch of other nodes linked to it by

```c
struct node *temp;
for (int i=0; i < no_of_nodes - 1; i++)
    {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> next = n;
        printf("Enter Node %d data : ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &(n -> data));

        temp = n;
    }
    temp -> next = NULL;
```

Then my **printNodes** function

```c
void printNodes(struct node *n)
{
    //printf("%d", n -> data);
    while(n != NULL)
    {   
        if (n -> next != NULL)
            printf("%d%s", n -> data, " -> ");
        else
            printf("%d%s", n -> data, " -> NULL\n");
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

The output will look like : **6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 3 -> NULL**

Now, i'm trying to insert a node at head node, i.e it becomes the head node and the original head becomes the second node.

```c
printf("Enter the head position (obviously 0) : ");
scanf("%d", &pos);
insertNode(head, pos);
printNodes(head);
```

The **insertNode** function :

```c
void insertNode (struct node *head, int pos)
{
    struct node *n;
    n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the Node data : ");
    scanf("%d", &(n -> data));

    if (pos == 0)
    {
        printf("Pos was 0, so HEAD\n");
        n -> next = head;
        head = n;
        printNodes(head);
    }
}
```

Ok, so the problem is that, the `printNodes(head)` actually prints the as intended..
but the
`printNodes(head);`after `insertNodes(head, pos)` doesn't print the updated Linked List,
why is the head not being updated ?
Where did I do wrong ?

The output I get is,
**Output:**

**Enter the Head position (obviously 0) : 0**

**Enter the Node data : 34**

**Pos was 0, so HEAD**

**34 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 3 -> NULL**       `[from printNodes(head) inside insertNodes(head, pos)]`

**6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 3 -> NULL**      `[from printNodes(head) after insertNodes(head, pos)]`

If anyone wants to look at the full code,
[here](https://katb.in/kisuwirixiq) you go.

Any help is appreciated..
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `insertNode` accepts the pointer to the head node by value. That is it deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer to the head node. Changing the copy does not reflect on the original pointer. The original pointer stays unchanged.

You need to pass the pointer by reference.

In C passing an object by reference means passing it indirectly through a pointer to it. Dereferencing the pointer you will get a direct access to the referenced object.

The function can look at least the following way

```
int insertNode( struct node **head, size_t pos )
{
    struct node *n = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = n != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        printf( "Enter the Node data : " );
        scanf( "%d", &n->data );

        while ( *head != NULL && pos-- )
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }

        n->next = *head;
        *head = n;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called like

```
insertNode( &head, pos );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, 
I'll try this out, but I still can't wrap my head over pointer to pointers...
Seems pretty confusing for me, no matter how many times I read about them.
And also why we use `size_t pos` ?
Does it automatically accommodate for the value of pos?

Comment: @adenosinetp10 size_t is unsigned integer type. So an object of the type can not be negative. You need not to check within the function whether pos is negative.

Comment: @adenosinetp10 For example if you have  declarations like int x = 10; int *p = &x; then you can change the object x using the pointer p like *p = 20; The same way if you have a pointer struct node *head = NULL; and a pointer to the pointer struct node **p = &head; then you can change the pointer head using the pointer p like *p = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );